# Get the first item in a json array in angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to get the first item in a json array that i get from a web service i call with a factory.

My controller:

```
CreateProjectIndex.controller('GroupCtrl', ['$scope', 'GetGroups',
function($scope, GetGroups){
   $scope.groups = GetGroups.getGroups();
   console.log($scope.groups);
   console.log($scope.groups[0]);
   $scope.group1 = $scope.groups[0];
}]);
```

My service:

```
'use strict';
var Groups = angular.module('GroupsService', ['ngResource']);

Groups.factory('GetGroups', ['$resource',
function($resource){
    return $resource('../../../api/Groups/GetGroups', {}, {
        getGroups : {method : 'GET', params:{}, headers: {'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}, isArray : true}
    });
}]);
```

the "console.log($scope.groups);" returns:

```
[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
0: Resource
    groupId: "361552"
    groupName: "1"
    __proto__: Resource
>1: Resource
>2: Resource
>3: Resource
>4: Resource
>5: Resource
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
```

While the " console.log($scope.groups[0]);" just returns "undefined".

Is there any way to get the first item in that object?

Comment: getGroup method is returning you the promise object not the data. try using something like GetGroups.getGroups().then(response){ $scope.groups = response};

Comment: Thanks for this, I had seen something about this, but it gives me 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'. Any idea what that can be about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Its working..

```
 CreateProjectIndex.controller('GroupCtrl', ['$scope', 'GetGroups',
    function($scope, GetGroups){
       $scope.groups = GetGroups.getGroups();
       $scope.groups.$promise.then(function(data) {
           alert(data[0].toSource());
       });

    }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I had seen something about this, but it gives me 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'. Any idea what that can be about?

Comment: Can you text that briefly, in which case you have got the TypeError.

Answer (score 2):

getGroup is returning a promise. Try this.

```
CreateProjectIndex.controller('GroupCtrl', ['$scope', 'GetGroups',
function($scope, GetGroups){
   GetGroups.getGroups()
    .then(function(data){
      $scope.groups = data;
    });
}]);
```

then when that request is 'resolved', $scope.groups will then become the data that you got back from that request.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had seen something about this, but it gives me 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'. Any idea what that can be about?